# Difference between async, detach and asyncDetached functions in async/await concept

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

If I understand correctly, `async, detach and asyncDetached` both create a Task (unit of concurrency), which in simple terms allows us to to execute `await` methods in it.
The only difference between `async` and `detach` I could find is the difference in property inheritance from *called* context (at least priority).

I haven't got any doubt about my misunderstanding between their difference.. but unfortunately couldn't find correct explanation even at WWDC videos.

Comment: thank you, but what about `asyncDetached`? Is there any kind of description for this function?

Comment: This is completely explained in the Structured Concurrency video (except `detach` which is old terminology)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names `async`, `detached` and `asyncDetach` have evolved over time. We don't call `async` (or `detached`) to start a unstructured task, now, but rather just [`Task(priority:operation:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856790-init). As [The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency: Unstructured Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID643) says:

> #### Unstructured Concurrency
>
> In addition to the structured approaches to concurrency described in the previous sections, Swift also supports unstructured concurrency. Unlike tasks that are part of a task group, an unstructured task doesn’t have a parent task. You have complete flexibility to manage unstructured tasks in whatever way your program needs, but you’re also completely responsible for their correctness. To create an unstructured task that runs on the current actor, call the [`Task.init(priority:operation:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856790-init) initializer. To create an unstructured task that’s not part of the current actor, known more specifically as a detached task, call the [`Task.detached(priority:operation:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856786-detached) class method. Both of these operations return a task handle that lets you interact with the task—for example, to wait for its result or to cancel it.

And [SE-0304](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0304-structured-concurrency.md#detached-tasks) says that:

> A *detached task* is an unstructured task that is independent of the context in which it is created, meaning that it does not inherit priority, task-local values, or the actor context.

Detached tasks also discussed extensively in the latter parts of WWDC 2021 video [Explore structured concurrency in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10134).

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's totally clear for me.